# Where to find the documentation for malloc() and related C-functions in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, malloc

The documentation Browser of Xcode is not aware of malloc. I want to read the documentation of these functions but can't find it. Where to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 4, when you search the documentation browser for `malloc`, you will see a result under "System Guides" called "iOS Manual Pages". This links to manpages for various BSD functions, including `malloc`.

Honestly, though, I would just go over to Terminal and type in `man malloc`, as the iOS environment is close enough to Darwin that it should rarely, if ever, make any difference to use the Darwin manpages.

Comment: It's also available online: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc.3.html